# Django: Context Processors and Class Based Views

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to include a form on certain pages to handle generating / emailing reports.

```
# context_processors.py
def sales_report_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SalesPdfForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.user.email:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.generate_pdf()
                messages.success(request, 'Report will be emailed to {} shortly.'.format(request.user.email))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'No email address set for {}'.format(request.user.username))
        return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        return {'sales_report_form': SalesPdfForm()}
```

The form is displayed on the pages but I'm having trouble posting

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /path/
"POST /path/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

To allow posting I moved the logic to a mixin and add it to each view. Is this the correct way to handle posting of a context processor form in Class Based Views?

```
class SalesReportMixin(object):
    """
    CBV mixin to handle the generation of sales reports.
    """
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'sales_report' in request.POST:
            form = SalesPdfForm(request.POST or None)
            if request.user.email:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.generate_pdf()
                    messages.success(request, 'Report will be emailed to {} shortly.'.format(request.user.email))
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'No email address set for {}'.format(request.user.username))
            return redirect(request.path)
        return super(SalesReportMixin, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Well working with code that has side-effects definitely is not a good idea. The idea of a context processor, is to fetch some data, and use it in *template rendering* to make it more convenient. Not to make changes to the database...

Comment: It would be better to change the form action to post to a single URL, e.g, `/sales-report/`. Then you can have a single view that handles the post request, and you don't need a mixin/context processor/middleware.

Comment: @Alasdair yeah, a lot easier. Thanks